# Will Oracle DB Upgrade assistant work to upgrade database on 10g server to 11g server

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g, migration, oracle11g

I have a Oracle server running 10g with various databases.

I have a Oracle server running 11g with no databases.

Can I use the Database Upgrade Assistant to upgrade one of the 10g databases onto the 11g server?

When I open the Database Upgrade Assistant it says pick a database but none are listed. I added an entry to TNS to see if that would do anything but it didn't.

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you're going to vote to close the question at least have the decency to say why, suggest a better way to word it or suggest a different stack exchange site to post it on.

Comment: both the Close Votes are for Off Topic.  I guess the voters think this is better suited to dba.se: http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database Upgrade Assistant will upgrade a database from 10g to 11g.
It will not migrate that database from one server to another server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an entry in the *oratab* file (usually in */etc* on *Linux* or in */var/opt/oracle* on *Solaris*) for the *10g* database to be upgraded? I believe *dbua* uses the *oratab* file for that.
The source database will need to be restarted at the beginning of the upgrade process and will be inaccessible during the migration. To avoid issues during the upgrade procedure you should run the pre-upgrade info script.

Answer (score 0):

DBUA upgrades database from 10.2.0.5.0 to 11.1.0.7, 11.2.0.2, 11.2.0.3 and 11.2.0.4 in 11g series. If you start dbua from any one of the above 11g versions, then your source db must from one of listed previous version otherwise it will not list.